# How can i Iterate through data returned in Ajax success?

Tags: php, ajaxform

How can I iterate to get `id` value? This is my array:

```
[{"email_id":"gayatri.dsf@detedu.org","Id":"216"}]
```

tried

```
<?php
    foreach($faculty as $value)
    {
       echo $value['Id'];
    }
?>
```

Gives an error

> Use of undefined constant Id - assumed Id

Comment: `$obj=json_decode($arr); echo $obj->id`?

Comment: The pending edit https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17979995 should be rejected, using blockquoting. It also doesn't make much of an (positive) impact on the post. Edit: @matloobHasnain Please **do not** use blockquotes for text. You have been flagged a few times for it and may get your editing privilege revoked.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17979995 --- ***Community♦ reviewed this 1 min ago: Approve*** - are you guys serious???

Comment: Hi, Please check the question and change the ratings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a json which is basically a string, to be more precise the given json contains a list (currently 1 element):

```
[{"email_id":"gayatri.dsf@detedu.org","Id":"216"}]
```

You need to convert it to an array first:

```
$jsonValues = json_decode($json, true); //here you will have an array of users (1 now)
foreach($jsonValues as $faculty) //for each user do something
{
    echo $faculty['Id'];
}
```

Comment: i am getting an error "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array"

Answer (score 1):

This is JSON format. First you have to decode it. Example:

```
$a = '[{"email_id":"gayatri.dsf@detedu.org","Id":"216"}]';

$dec = json_decode($a);

echo $dec[0]->Id;
```

> Result: 216

Decoded you have an array, containing exactly one object. You have to access the object properties with `->` then.

With JSON `[]` brackets means an array, while `{}` brackets mean objects. Learn more: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON

Comment: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_Object_Notation can you find an English version of this page? My German is very limited ;-) and others I'm sure.

Comment: Sure, sorry: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON

Comment: I am getting an error Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: Try var_dump($dec); and see what the result is!